# Strange Behaviour of HTC One X battery

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, battery, htc-one-x

maybe someone recognizes my problem or has had it himself. My problem is as follows:

Normally I turn my phone of over night.

Battery Monday evening 50%, Tuesday morning 23%

Battery Tuesday evening 79%, Wednesday morning 45%

Turned of accelerated start on Wednesday as I read this might help.

Wednesday evening: 64%, Thursday morning 74%

Didn't turn off my phone tonight and the battery lvl stayed the same at 84% tonight.

As this behaviour makes absolutely no sense, I'm not sure wether my battery is going to die soon or whatever else the problem might be.

EDIT:
After a week of not turning it off during the night, the battery keeps stable over night (about 5% loss in 7 hours). Only thing worth mentioning: When using Apps, the battery drops faster than normal

Comment: Edit: Maybe someone can explain it now ;)